# при удалении картинки из сервера php, она возвращается назад

Tags: php, изображения

Вот простой код загрузки картинки на php (просто пример) index.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/" . $name);
?>
```

и html форма index.php:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit" name="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Возникла такая проблема, что когда я пытаюсь удалить картинку из сервера (простым путем, зайдя в папку uploads, и удалив её от туда) а затем зайдя назад на страницу и перезагрузить её, то загруженная картинка появляется опять в папке куда мы её загружали. Я новичок в этом, и не понимаю в чем проблема, буду рад если кто-то поможет.)

Comment: а при обновлении страницы вы подтверждаете отправку формы ещё раз?

Comment: нет, просто после загрузки удаляю фото, а за тем обновляю страницу

Comment: Все в порядке, я понял в чем ошибка)

Comment: Не поделитесь??

Comment: при обновлении страницы автоматом подтверждал отправку)) Протупил немного...)

Comment: Как раз то что я и написал выше)

Comment: Да)) А возможно ли как-то обойти уведомление повторной отправки формы после обновления страницы?

Comment: Нет. Только если перенесёте скрипт в на отдельную страницу, action="func/images.php", а в конец скрипта просто поставить редирект на предыдущую страницу